# Do Americans usually pronounce "HOW TO LOVE" /haʊdʌv/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

The Weekend is [singing](https://youtu.be/4NRXx6U8ABQ?t=54)

> MAYBE YOU CAN SHOW ME **HOW TO LOVE**

where "HOW TO LOVE" sounds like /haʊdʌv/.

Do Americans usually pronounce "HOW TO LOVE" /haʊdʌv/?

Answer (score 1):

*How to love* in that song sounds closer to [haː ɾə lʌv] (or perhaps [həː **ɾ**ə lʌv]). It's certainly not [haʊdʌv].

The reason why the *t* in *to* sounds like *d* is 'flapping' (or 'tapping'). In most American accents, *d* and *t* before unstressed vowels are usually pronounced with a flap—[**ɾ**]—in which the tip of the tongue taps very quickly against the alveolar ridge. So *water* is pronounced [ˈwɑːɾɚ], *better* [ˈbɛɾɚ], *rider* [ˈɹaɪɾɚ] (or [ˈɹʌɪɾɚ] in some accents).

In the phrase *how to love*, the *t* comes before an unstressed vowel so it's pronounced as a tap—[ɾ].